# Thread deadlock example in C#

Tags: c#, deadlock

Can someone give an example of how thread deadlock can be caused in the C# language?

Comment: He didn't tagged it as homework.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
static object object1 = new object();
static object object2 = new object();

public static void ObliviousFunction()
{
    lock (object1)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait for the blind to lead
        lock (object2)
        {
        }
    }
}

public static void BlindFunction()
{
    lock (object2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait for oblivion
        lock (object1)
        {
        }
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread((ThreadStart)ObliviousFunction);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread((ThreadStart)BlindFunction);

    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        // Stare at the two threads in deadlock.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I came to this question to describe something like this.  Order of lock acquisition is a very common concern in practice.  Rule of thumb: if you need to have 2 locks held at the same time they should be acquired and released in a predictable and consistent order.

Answer (score 8):

From [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization_Contexts)

> At the other end of the scale,
>   separate synchronization contexts
>   invite deadlocks. Here's an example:

```
[Synchronization]
public class Deadlock : ContextBoundObject {
    public DeadLock Other;
    public void Demo() { Thread.Sleep (1000); Other.Hello(); }
    void Hello() { Console.WriteLine ("hello"); }
}
public class Test {
    static void Main() {
    Deadlock dead1 = new Deadlock();
    Deadlock dead2 = new Deadlock();
    dead1.Other = dead2;
    dead2.Other = dead1;
    new Thread (dead1.Demo).Start();
    dead2.Demo();
}
```

> Because each instance of Deadlock is
>   created within Test – an
>   unsynchronized class – each instance
>   will gets its own synchronization
>   context, and hence, its own lock. When
>   the two objects call upon each other,
>   it doesn't take long for the deadlock
>   to occur (one second, to be precise!)
>   The problem would be particularly
>   insidious if the Deadlock and Test
>   classes were written by different
>   programming teams. It may be
>   unreasonable to expect those
>   responsible for the Test class to be
>   even aware of their transgression, let
>   alone know how to go about resolving
>   it. This is in contrast to explicit
>   locks, where deadlocks are usually
>   more obvious.