# How to successfully cause deadlock

Tags: c#, deadlock

I'm trying to cause deadlock in C# for simulation purposes. Just a quick program.

Could anyone kindly suggest some ideas for doing so?

Comment: See the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2411456/441574

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543140/deadlock-sample-in-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

## Thread 1:

```
lock (A) {

lock (B) { }

}
```

## Thread 2:

```
lock (B) {

lock (A) { }

}
```

Comment: +1 great example. I have burnt my fingers with it.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Program
{
    static object _locker1 = new object();
    static object _locker2 = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread first = new Thread(FirstThread);
        first.Start();

        Thread second = new Thread(SecondThread);
        second.Start();

    }

    static void FirstThread(object obj)
    {
        // Lock resource 1
        lock(_locker1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread 1: locked resource 1");

            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException e) {}

            lock(_locker2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread 1: locked resource 2");
            }
        }
    }

    static void SecondThread(object obj)
    {
        // Lock resource 1
        lock (_locker2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread 2: locked resource 2");

            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException e) { }

            lock (_locker1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread 2: locked resource 1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

credits to: http://www.java-forums.org/java-lang/7346-how-create-simple-deadlock.html